# CSS grid 2 columns

Tags: css, css-grid

I need to create this grid with css grid:

[image]

my code:

```
display grid
grid-template-areas:  "d1 d1 d1 d2 d2 d2 d3 d3 d4 d4 d4"\
                      "d1 d1 d1 d5 d5 d5 d5 d6 d6 d6 d6"
```

Thats work, but i have a problem. When im resizing browser, columns fit randomly from. How i can fix size on 25fr 26fr 23fr 26fr?

Im trying grid-template-columns: 25fr 26fr 23fr 26fr, but how i can set values for second row 25fr 35fr 40fr?

Comment: in the second row you have 3 items so how you want to be 40fr 60fr ?

Comment: actually 25fr 35fr 40fr

Comment: avoid using "prime number" like 23 .. find more suitable number to be able to find a shared multiplier

Comment: are u know how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to devide your layout into 5 columns, and do some math:
[image]

And the grid layout you need is this:

```css
grid-template-areas:  "d1 d2 d3 d3 d4"
                      "d1 d5 d5 d6 d6";
grid-template-columns: 25fr 26fr 9fr 14fr 26fr;
```

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas:  "d1 d2 d3 d3 d4"
                        "d1 d5 d5 d6 d6";
  grid-auto-rows: 80px;
  grid-template-columns: 25fr 26fr 9fr 14fr 26fr;
  grid-gap: 6px;
}

.grid img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.grid img:nth-child(1) {
  grid-area: d1;
}
.grid img:nth-child(2) {
  grid-area: d2;
}
.grid img:nth-child(3) {
  grid-area: d3;
}
.grid img:nth-child(4) {
  grid-area: d4;
}
.grid img:nth-child(5) {
  grid-area: d5;
}
.grid img:nth-child(6) {
  grid-area: d6;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/640/480" />
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/640/480" />
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/640/480" />
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/640/480" />
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/640/480" />
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/640/480" />
</div>
```